# Reading a 1.2V-8.8V Signal into a 5V Arduino Input

Tags: arduino, voltage, adc, signal, voltage-divider

An analog DC signal that ranges from 1.2V to 8.8V ([from a thermocouple amplifier](http://www.playingwithfusion.com/productview.php?pdid=21&catid=1001)) is to be read from a input pin on the Arduino that reads 0V to 5V.

Other that using a potential divider consisting of 2 resistors to drop the signal down to 0.6V to 4.4V, is there an alternative method that exist, like one that uses a IC?

Answer (score 1):

There will be resistors on some levels. If you like ICs, you can buy IC which contains multiple resistors:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/4604X-101-103LF/4604X-101-103LF-ND/3593680

Or you could use fixed-gain amplifier which has resistors + amplifier in one package. But this will be an overkill, as your output is already from amplifier, plus most fixed-gain amplifiers have gain > 1

Or you can use ADC which takes -10V..+10V range and returns I2C data such as MAX127/MAX128.

Or you could just connect amplifier directly to Arduino. Output will only exceed 5V if temperature is > 590C. What is the max temperature of the thing you are trying to measure?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two equal value resistors such as 10K 0.1% on each amplifier output. They're not expensive. Since the amplifier output goes to 9.9V on open T/C this will prevent damage to the AVR from a dead thermocouple or open connection (or unplugged sensor).

There's no need of using an IC, but if you really want to use something IC-like you can use an Linear Technology [LT5400](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/5400fc.pdf) (each one will handle two channels).